# Proposition 4.2 in Goerss & Jardine's *Simplicial homotopy theory*

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm having trouble filling in a detail in Goerss and Jardine's book [*Simplicial homotopy theory*](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf). Their *Proposition 4.2* claims that two classes of monomorphisms $\mathbf{B}_2\subset\mathbf{B}_3$ in the category of simplicial sets define the same saturated class, in their notation, $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}=M_{\mathbf{B}_3}$.

> How do you prove $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}=M_{\mathbf{B}_3}$?

I'm following their proof suggestion. The first few paragraphs are to introduce notation; there is a specific point that I don't see how to deal with (see the highlighted bit at the end).

---

$\mathbf{B}_2$ is the class of all inclusions
$$\Delta^1\times\partial\Delta^n\underset{e\times\Delta^n}{\cup}e\times\Delta^n\;\hookrightarrow\; \Delta^1\times\Delta^n$$
(simply written $\Delta^1\times\partial\Delta^n \cup e\times\Delta^n\hookrightarrow\Delta^1\times\Delta^n$) with $e=0,1$, while

$\mathbf{B}_3$ is the class of all inclusions
$$\Delta^1\times A\cup e\times X\;\hookrightarrow\; \Delta^1\times X$$
again, $e=0,1$, where $A\hookrightarrow X$ is an arbitrary monomorphism.

---

Obvisouly $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}\subset M_{\mathbf{B}_3}$. The text provides an indication as to how to prove the reverse inclusion: for every inclusion $A\subset X$, $X$ is obtained from $A$ by adjoining cells. Inspired by the proof of *Corollary 4.6*, I tried to prove that the class $\cal C$ of all monomorphisms $A\hookrightarrow X$ such that $\left(\Delta^1\times A\cup e\times X\;\hookrightarrow\; \Delta^1\times X\right)\in M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$ is a saturated class (minus the stability by retracts part).

By definition of $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$, $\cal C$ contains all boundary inclusions $\partial\Delta^n\subset\Delta^n$. Also, every inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$, $X$ can be recovered as a colimit of complexes $X^{(n)}$, $n\geq -1$, with $X^{(-1)}=A$ and $X^{(n)}$ is obtained from $X^{(n-1)}$ by adjoining cells, i.e. as a pushout diagram
$$\begin{matrix}
\coprod\partial\Delta^n & \hookrightarrow & \coprod\Delta^n\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
X^{(n-1)} &\rightarrow & X^{(n)}
\end{matrix}$$
(the coproduct is taken over all non-degenerate $n$-simplices in $X$ that aren't already in $A$)
Then stability by transfinite composition of $\cal C$ *would guarantee* that the inclusion
$$A\hookrightarrow\mathrm{colim}_n X^{(n)}$$ is in $\cal C$, but this inclusion is isomorphic to the original inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$ and so $\cal C$ would be the class of all monomorphisms, proving $M_{\mathbf{B}_3}\subset M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$

---

> I can prove that $\cal C$ contains all isomorphisms, is closed under pushouts and arbitrary coproducts, *but I don't see why it is stable under countable compositions* (I don't think I need stability under retracts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the solution isn't that bad. Consider an infinite sequence of monomorphisms in $\cal C$
$$A=A_1\overset{i_1}{\hookrightarrow}A_2\overset{i_2}{\hookrightarrow}A_3\overset{i_3}{\hookrightarrow}\cdots\hookrightarrow\mathrm{colim}_n\,A_n=X$$
We need to prove that the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$ is still in $\cal C$, that is, that the inclusion 
$$\Delta^1\times A\cup e\times X\;\hookrightarrow\;\Delta^1\times X$$ is in $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$, for $e=0,1$. But this is because for any $n$, the square below is a pushout:
$$\begin{matrix}
\Delta^1\times A_n\cup e\times A_{n+1} & \hookrightarrow & \Delta^1\times A_{n+1}\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\Delta^1\times A_n\cup e\times X &\to&\Delta^1\times A_{n+1}\cup e\times X
\end{matrix}$$
and since the top morphism is in $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$ by hypothesis, so is the monomorphism
$$\underbrace{\Delta^1\times A_n\cup e\times X}_{B_n} \;\hookrightarrow\;\underbrace{\Delta^1\times A_{n+1}\cup e\times X}_{B_{n+1}}$$
By construction, $B_1=\Delta^1\times A\cup e\times X$, and $\mathrm{colim}_n\,B_n=\Delta^1\times X$, and the stability by countable compositions of $M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$ implies that the inclusion
$$\left(\Delta^1\times A\cup e\times X\,\hookrightarrow\,\Delta^1\times X\right)\in M_{\mathbf{B}_2}$$
i.e. $\left(A\hookrightarrow X\right)\in\cal C$.

---

Everything about this proof still works for a general inclusion $K\subset L$ rather than the two inclusions $d^0,d^1:\Delta^0\hookrightarrow\Delta^1$, or for a collection of inclusions.

Answer (score 1):

While the above solution is correct, I just wanted to remark that this proof can also be found as Theorem 2.2.1 (page 61) in the book of [Gabriel-Zisman](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-85844-4).